# How to change font in jMeter output graphs

Tags: graph, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using one of jMeter plugins 'JP@GC response times over time' to display results and I would like to change the look of that graph.

Is there any way to do so ? For instance changing the font in the above mentioned graph.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's kind of relying on Java defaults which are in `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/fontconfig.properties.src` so you'll have to either change Java defaults (it'll have global level) or patch source code of Response Times Over Time listener.

If you need once-only hack you can use [Beanshell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) somewhere at the very beginning of your script to change font family, size, etc on-the-fly. See following example for details:

```
  import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.Enumeration;

Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();   
 while (keys.hasMoreElements()){
        Object key = keys.nextElement();
        Object value = UIManager.get(key);
        if (value instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource) {
            UIManager.put(key, new FontUIResource(new Font("MS Mincho", Font.PLAIN, 50)));
        }
    }
```

[image: Example of changing font JMeter family and size via Beanshell]